How to make 3D points scale properly in appearance?
I have this 3D plot in pgf but I have an issue with scaling. The points s_3 and s_4 should have the same length but they appear not: s_3 appears bigger than s_4 why?
\documentclass{standalone} % You can use article, report, or standalone
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % Ensure compatibility with newer pgfplots features

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={120}{30}, % Adjust the view angle
        axis lines=middle,
        xlabel={$ \phi_3(t) $},
        ylabel={$ \phi_1(t) $},
        zlabel={$ \phi_2(t) $},
        xmin=-2, xmax=2,
        ymin=-2, ymax=2,
        zmin=-2, zmax=2, 
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        ztick=\empty,
        grid=major,
        width=14cm,
        height=14cm,
        axis line style={thick,->,>=latex}, % Add arrows to the positive axes
        axis equal,
        unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
        scale=1.2
    ]
    % Plot the points
    \addplot3[only marks, blue, mark=*] coordinates {
        (0, 1.414, 0)   % s1 = (sqrt(2), 0, 0)
        (0, 0, 1.414)   % s2 = (0, sqrt(2), 0)
        (1, 0, -1.414)  % s3 = (0, -sqrt(2), 1)
        (1, 1.414, 0)   % s4 = (sqrt(2), 0, 1)
    };

    % Labels for the points
    \node at (axis cs: 0, 1.414, 0.6) [blue, anchor=north] {$\mathbf{s}_1$};
    \node at (axis cs: 0, 0, 1.6) [blue, anchor=west] {$\mathbf{s}_2$};
    \node at (axis cs: 1, 0, -1.6) [blue, anchor=east] {$\mathbf{s}_3$};
    \node at (axis cs: 0.7, 1.2, 0) [blue, anchor=north west] {$\mathbf{s}_4$};
    \draw[ultra thick, blue] (axis cs:0,0,0) -- (axis cs: 0, 1.414, 0);
    \draw[ultra thick, blue] (axis cs:0,0,0) -- (axis cs: 0, 0, 1.414);
    \draw[ultra thick, blue] (axis cs:0,0,0) -- (axis cs: 1, 0, -1.414);
    \draw[ultra thick, blue] (axis cs:0,0,0) -- (axis cs: 1, 1.414, 0);
    \node at (axis cs: 0, 0.7, 0.2) {$\sqrt{2}$};
    \node at (axis cs: 0, 0.2, 0.8) {$\sqrt{2}$};
    \node at (axis cs: 0.2, -0.1, -1.2) {$\sqrt{3}$};
    \node at (axis cs: 0.7, 0.6, 0) {$\sqrt{3}$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Including a screenshot might attract more solutions ...

I edited the question to add a screenshot.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=14cm, axis equal,
view={120}{30},
axis lines=middle, ticks=none,
xlabel=x, ylabel=y, zlabel=z,
xmin=-2, xmax=2,
ymin=-2, ymax=2,
zmin=-2, zmax=2, 
axis line style={thick,-latex},
]
\newcommand{\drawvec}[4]{
\draw[#4] (0,0,0) -- ({#1},{#2},{#3});
\draw[#4, -, thin, densely dotted] ({#1},0,0) -- ({#1},{#2},0) -- (0,{#2},0) ({#1},{#2},0) -- ({#1},{#2},{#3});
}
\drawvec{0}{sqrt(2)}{0}{blue, ->, ultra thick}
\drawvec{0}{0}{sqrt(2)}{blue, ->, ultra thick}
\drawvec{1}{0}{-sqrt(2)}{blue, ->, ultra thick}
\drawvec{1}{sqrt(2)}{0}{blue, ->, ultra thick}
\drawvec{1}{1}{1}{red, ->, ultra thick}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


